# Gradle Build Failed - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMethodInsn

Tags: java, android, gradle, flutter

I just started a new Flutter project, which uses Gradle through Android Studio.  All of my Gradle builds have been getting stuck with the error messages below.  I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio and the emulator, but that didn't fix the issue.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.plugin.management.internal.DefaultPluginResolutionStrategy.
> Could not generate a decorated class for type DefaultPluginResolutionStrategy.
   > org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMethodInsn(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Here is the stacktrace data:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.plugin.management.internal.DefaultPluginResolutionStrategy.
> Could not generate a decorated class for type DefaultPluginResolutionStrategy.
   > org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMethodInsn(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.reflect.ObjectInstantiationException: Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.plugin.management.internal.DefaultPluginResolutionStrategy.
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.doCreate(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.newInstance(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:55)
        at org.gradle.plugin.internal.PluginUsePluginServiceRegistry$BuildScopeServices.createPluginResolutionStrategy(PluginUsePluginServiceRegistry.java:113)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:833)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:765)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:556)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:614)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:778)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:764)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:556)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:614)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:303)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:287)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:282)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildScopeServices.defaultScriptPluginFactory(BuildScopeServices.java:319)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory(BuildScopeServices.java:306)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:833)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:765)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:556)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:614)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:778)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:764)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:556)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:614)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:778)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:764)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:556)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:614)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:303)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:287)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:282)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.doNewInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:133)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.newInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:80)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.<init>(DefaultRootBuildState.java:46)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildRegistry.createRootBuild(DefaultIncludedBuildRegistry.java:80)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:68)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:27)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.instantiation.ClassGenerationException: Could not generate a decorated class for type DefaultPluginResolutionStrategy.
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.AbstractClassGenerator.generateUnderLock(AbstractClassGenerator.java:224)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.AbstractClassGenerator.lambda$new$0(AbstractClassGenerator.java:117)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCrossBuildInMemoryCacheFactory$AbstractCrossBuildInMemoryCache.get(DefaultCrossBuildInMemoryCacheFactory.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:156)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.AsmBackedClassGenerator.generate(AsmBackedClassGenerator.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.ParamsMatchingConstructorSelector.forParams(ParamsMatchingConstructorSelector.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.doCreate(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:61)
        ... 85 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMethodInsn(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.AsmBackedClassGenerator$ClassBuilderImpl.generateToStringSupport(AsmBackedClassGenerator.java:1531)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.AsmBackedClassGenerator$ClassBuilderImpl.startClass(AsmBackedClassGenerator.java:499)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.AsmBackedClassGenerator$ClassInspectionVisitorImpl.builder(AsmBackedClassGenerator.java:323)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.AbstractClassGenerator.generateUnderLock(AbstractClassGenerator.java:202)
        ... 91 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 828ms
```

It looks like it's getting hung up on `org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMethodInsn`, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: I solved this issue by re-imaging my Mac.  Prior to that I tried removing all Flutter, Gradle, and Android Studio directories/files.  I also tried replacing my JDK with several other versions and even tried removing and reinstalling my JRE, none of which worked.  There must have been some deep-seeded dependency conflicts somewhere in my system.